# How can I use strstr() with a filename

Tags: c, shell

I'm trying to implement the * shell wildcard in a minishell.
I wrote a program that compares the part after * with the current directory's filenames.

After doing some testing, the part that doesn't seem to work is the strstr function, it sends a NULL pointer even when getting to a filename that contains the input substring:

```
if (strstr(ent->d_name,wildcard)!= NULL)
```

For example, if I do cat *filename in a folder containing a file named filename, the program will read "filename", then compare it to "filename" yet will result in a NULL pointer.

This is what the code looks like

```
int wildcardCheck( char* input ) {
    int returnflag;

    if( strstr( input, "*" ) != NULL ) {
        int i;
        char* wildcard;
        wildcard = strstr( input, "*" );
        strcpy( wildcard, wildcard + 1 ); // +1 excludes wildcard (*)
        printf( "it's %s", wildcard );

        // Open current directory and get all entities
        struct dirent* ent;
        DIR* dir = opendir( "." );
        char* arg;

        while( (ent = readdir( dir )) != NULL ) {
            // If the entity filename matches the regular expression
            printf( " file %s\n", ent->d_name );
            if( strstr( ent->d_name, wildcard ) != NULL ) {
                arg = malloc( (sizeof( char ) * strlen( ent->d_name )) + 1 );
                strcpy( arg, ent->d_name );
                // Substitutes the argument containing the wildcard with the new filename
                input = strtok( input, "*" );

                // We only substitute one filename in this loop and add the rest later, hence break
                input = strcat( input, arg );
                printf( "arg is%s\n", arg );
                printf( "final input is%s", input );
                free( arg );
                returnflag = 1;
                break;
            }
            else printf( "didn't enter %d : strstr( %s, %s ) == NULL\n", 3, ent->d_name, wildcard );
        }


        closedir( dir );

    }
```

Here's the testing of the current program:

```
mysh-master$ cat *ilename
it's ilename


file filename
didn't enter 3 : strstr( filename, ilename
) == NULL

0
cat: ilename: No such file or directory
Exit status : 1
```

Comment: `strcpy(wildcard, wildcard + 1);` it is UB to use overlapping objects with `strcpy()`, try `memmove(wildcard, wildcard + 1, strlen(wildcard));`

Comment: What @pmg said, or more simply `wildcard++` - no need to copy or move anything.

Comment: D'oh! Of course `wildcard++`! But I'm keeping my "over achiever" comment for completeness.

Comment: Your error report would more usefully report `else printf( "didn't enter %d : strstr( %s, %s ) == NULL\n", 3, ent->d_name, wildcard );` Or just use a debugger - faster than SO!  At least include the debug output you _do_ have.

Comment: @Clifford did just that, and i clearly have a file name that would match my input

Comment: @otpnocturne ; I am sure it _is_ clear, but you are still asking us to take your word for it.  It is not unreasonable to expect the same diagnostic evidence you are using to draw the conclusion you have - it will save time if only to avoid having to analyse the code to confirm your assertion to start with.  Because clearly `strstr()` is unlikely to be broken and a filename is just a string - there is nothing special that would cause `strstr()` not to work. It would have been quicker to copy & paste your debug output into the question that it would to have argued about it.

Comment: @Clifford done, i also removed some of the files, just kept the one that should work  with strstr

Answer (score 2):

The debug output:

```
didn't enter 3 : strstr( filename, ilename
) == NULL
```

from

```
else printf( "didn't enter %d : strstr( %s, %s ) == NULL\n", 3, ent->d_name, wildcard );
```

indicates that `wildcard == "ilename\n"` - i.e. it has a newline so will not match `"filename"` without a newline.